# how to bypass text captcha using selininum

Tags: python, captcha

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXFPf.png)

The website i am trying to bypass is http://results.jntuh.ac.in/
using selenium with python on pi3 need it for collage project,
is there any way o can bypass text captcha , i can copy the text from catch and paste it in the textbox !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Make sure to show what you've already done, so people can see where they can help you most and help improve. If you find that an answer has helped you, click the checkmark on the left of it to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pair the `.execute_script()` method with a JavaScript snippet which will do it for you. This works by getting the value of the input CAPTCHA, then setting it to the value of the input field.

```py
# Execute a script in the browser
browser.execute_script("""

// Set the value of the input to the value of the CAPTCHA text
document.querySelector("#txtInput").value = document.querySelector("#txtCaptcha").value

""")
```

Comment: It worked but i got a new problem i cant click on submit button as it doesn't contain an id  how can i click on submit button , for reference  <input type="submit" value="Submit">

Comment: You can get the form itself in JavaScript, since the ID of your form is 'myForm'. Then, you can call the implemented `.onsubmit` function that the website has provided. If you pair this all together, then you can do another `browser.execute_script()` function to call the JavaScript and run the script and submit the form for you. All together, the code you will need should look something like this- `browser.execute_script("""document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit();""")`. If my answer helped you & was correct, then make sure to click the check mark next to it to mark it as valid.

Comment: on submit doesnt work, please have a look https://gist.github.com/lARSHADl/ddcd0f4a6cd0a6b43ccd2949d567cf1d

Comment: First of all, if you have a new error or question, please ask it in a new question/thread on this website. Second, this website is not meant for writing code or analyzing it in it's entirety, you have to show your thought process and at the least, why it isn't working. You can't just dump your code here and tell me to fix it, that's not what this place is meant for. **Lastly, if my first answer did help you and is correct, then mark it as valid using the checkmark on the left of it.**